# Can i use scanf for strings?

Tags: objective-c

I cant get the input/output to work correctly. Please help.

Here is my code...

```
    char choice1;

    printf("This is a text game! You will be shown what is going on");
    printf("\nand it is up to you to decide what to do.");

    printf("\n\nThere is a gem on the ground.");
    printf("\nWhat do you want to do");
    printf("\n>");


    scanf("%c", &choice1);

    if (choice1 == pick up gem) {
        printf("Got Gem");
    }
```

Comment: "Does anyone now how to make a text adventure game in objective-c?" -Yes.

Comment: What is `pick up gem` ? You subject line has little relevance to your problem.

Comment: Maybe you need to unmake the input words?

Comment: the pick up gem is supposed to be what the user should type in. I am new to objective c, and am just tying to learn it. How should i fix my code?

Comment: how do i unmake input words? Delete them?

Comment: Your Objective-C code doesn't work because your C code doesn't work.

Comment: Why was this closed? The question is about making some code work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%c` is for inputting a single character, not a string. If you want to allow a user to input more than a single character then you need something like:

```
char string[256];
fgets(string, 255, stdin);

if (strcmp(string, "pick up gem\n") == 0) {
    printf("Got Gem");
}
```

BTW - this is not Objective-C, this is C.

And bad things will happen if the user enters more than 256 characters.

**Update**: It turns out that `scanf` only grabs the first word of the input. Using `fgets` reads up through the newline.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but will this work in objective-c? Aslo i tried using a string for the input but i cant seem to find a scanf % for strings.

Comment: What do you mean by "string"? A C-string like I used in my answer (with `%s`) or an Objective-C (really Cocoa) `NSString`? And yes, since Objective-C is a superset of C, this code works fine in Objective-C.

Comment: by string i mean saying NSString blah blah blah, then saying scanf("% then whatever should go next.

Comment: `scanf` doesn't work with `NSString`. `scanf` is a C function that only works with C data type, not classes like `NSString`. What I posted in my answer will work with basic C-strings.

Comment: ok, will it work for a full blown long text game? Assuming I add in classes and things like that.

Comment: It worked for Zork back in the day, it will work for you now.

Comment: Cool, thank you so much. Also thanks for not marking my question down.

Comment: Umm... i tried it  and it did not work, i typed it in but it did not display anything

Comment: Oh yeah, the string will probably have a newline at the end. See my updated answer.

Comment: still nothing, the update will just appear above right?

Comment: Found the issue. See my updated answer.

Comment: Can You mark my post back up, i fixed it.

Comment: I never down voted it. But I did vote to reopen it.

Comment: Thanks, but could you do my other posts as well.